# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier PriorityNode.prototype.removeChildren

Tags: node.js, create-react-app

Cannot run `create-react-app start`.

```
/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/priority.js:81
PriorityNode.prototype.removeChildren = function removeChildren () {
^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/noah/Projects/project-1/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport.js:18:22)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: What's in line 80 and 79?

Comment: @melpomene I don't have a vm.js in my project. That must be from somewhere else.

Comment: I mean in `node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/priority.js`.

Comment: @melpomene Again, it's a package I didn't write. There is a typo above there, it's plain to see. But I've dropped back a version on spdy. Will do the same for spdy-transport. I of course looked on several related Github issue pages and Googled, but saw no one else facing the issue. Pretty weird.

Answer (score 3):

I'm betting you or someone on your team encountered the "AssertionError" bug detailed here: https://github.com/spdy-http2/spdy-transport/issues/47. Then that person used this or a similar workaround to fix it: https://github.com/spdy-http2/spdy-transport/issues/47#issuecomment-369020176

The workaround involves hacking spdy-transport on the fly by creating a JS script that edits `node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/priority.js`, then running it after every install. The typical way to do this would be setting it as a post-install script in package.json. My theory is that someone on your team already did this. Check the `"scripts"` section of your package.json for a line like this:

```
"postinstall": "node ./quickfix.js"
```

Why does it crash now? The spdy team **finally** merged in a bugfix (https://github.com/spdy-http2/spdy-transport/pull/57) which fixes the problem and makes the hack unnecessary. Since the workaround was never more than a temporary hack, it isn't very robust. It still tries to "fix" the updated file, which now only breaks it.

Remove the postinstall script, delete and reinstall `node_modules/spdy-transport`, and you should be fine.